# Add array values into MongoDB where element is not in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB, this is the simplified structure of my `account` document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a70a60ca7fbc476caea5e59"),
    "templates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Password Reset",
            "content" : "AAAAAAAA"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Welcome Message",
            "content" : "BBBBBB"
        }
     ]
}
```

There's a similar `default_templates` collection

```
let accnt = await Account.findOne({ _id: req.account._id }, { templates: 1 });
let defaults = await DefaultTemplate.find({}).lean();
```

My goal is to find the missing templates under account and grab them from defaults. (a) I need to upsert `templates` if it doesn't exist in an account and (b) I don't want to update a template if it already exists in an account.

I've tried the following:

```
if (!accnt.templates || accnt.templates.length < defaults.length) {

  const accountTemplates = _.filter(accnt.templates, 'name');
  const templateNames = _.map(accountTemplates, 'name');

  Account.update({ _id: req.account._id, 'templates.name' : { $nin: templateNames } },
      { '$push': { 'templates': { '$each' : defaults } } }, { 'upsert' : true },
      function(err, result) {
        Logger.error('error %o', err);
        Logger.debug('result %o', result);
      }
  );
}
```

This succeeds at the upsert but it will enter all default templates even if there's a matching name in `templateNames`. I've verified that `templateNames` array is correct and I've also tried using `$addToSet` instead of `$push`, so I must not understand Mongo subdoc queries.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've gotten this to work by simply removing elements from the defaults array before updating, but I'd still like to know how this could be accomplished with Mongoose.

Comment: what does `templateNames` and `defaults` contain?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet defaults contains doc/schema identical to the one shown above for `account` templateNames contains an array of those `name` properties on that same doc (e.g., `[ "Password Reset", "Welcome Message" ]`)

Comment: upsert works on document level, not sub-documents. addToSet works (like doesn't push) only when both name and content are identical. Your approach is how it supposed to work.

Comment: The only thing is $nin is not doing what you expect. It matches only documents where no single template with name from templateNames, which is somehow different to "find the missing templates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) operation in mongodb

```
Account.bulkWrite(
  req.body.accountTemplates.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: req.account._id, 'templates.name' : { $ne: data.name } },
        update: { $push: { templates: { $each : data } } },
        upsert : true
      }
    })
  )
})
```