# mongoDB upsert query

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I am trying to make an upsert in mongo collection which involves maintaining a combination subject names and count of occurences, but at the same time maintaining only unique subject names. I am not able to use $addToSet because count should be part of each subject, whereas only the subject should be unique.

Here is the structure I am expecting to upsert.

```
{
 "account": "abc123",
 "subjects": [
    {
        "subject": "s1",
        "count": 4,

    },
    {
        "subject": "s2",
        "count": 2,

    }
]
```

So the upsert query is something like -

```
selector := bson.M{"accountid": AccountId}
updator := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"accountid": AccountId}, 
         "$addToSet": bson.M{"subjects": Subject}}
```

Not sure how to add count to this query within the index of the subject which got added/updated.

Comment: how your `Subject` object looks like?

Comment: "accountid" : "wellnesstest1",
   "subjects" : [
    {
   "name" : "urn:nimble:array:c55e5b0d-a1a9-42de-bee9-930874e39879",
   "count" : 1
  },
  {
   "name" : "urn:nimble:volume:AF-160766",
   "count" : 1
  },

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549326/add-array-values-into-mongodb-where-element-is-not-in-array/51563408#51563408