# Mongoose add multiple object to array if not exist based

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How to add multiple objects to array based on key?

I need to add multiple objects in **one** query, check if each `object key` doesn't exist or duplicate, else add object. (`label` can be duplicate)

**Schema**

```
new Schema({
      additional: [
        {
          key: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
          label: { type: String, required: true }
        }
      ]
})
```

request payload:

```
[ {key: "city", label: "CITY"}, {key: "gender", label: "GENDER"}
, {key: "city" ,label: "CITY1"}, {key: "city2", label: "CITY"}]
```

**Expected results:**

```
[
 {key: "city", label: "CITY"},
 {key: "gender", label: "GENDER"},
 {key: "city2", label: "CITY"}
]
```

I tried to find solutions but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [**`bulkWrite`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) operation in mongodb

Suppose you have following payload to update

```
const payload = [
  { key: "city", label: "CITY" }, { key: "gender", label: "GENDER" },
  { key: "city", label: "CITY1" }, { key: "city2", label: "CITY" }
]
```

Query to update documents in bulk

```
Model.bulkWrite(
  payload.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { '_id': 'xxxx', 'additional.key' : { $ne: data.key } },
        update: { $push: { additional: data } }
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Which will send a request in bulk to update like this

```
bulkWrite([
  { updateOne: { filter: { '_id': 'xxxx', 'additional.key' : { $ne: data.key } }, update: { $push: { additional: data } } } },
  { updateOne: { filter: { '_id': 'xxxx', 'additional.key' : { $ne: data.key } }, update: { $push: { additional: data } } } }
])
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. it's add empty doc. did you test that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549326/add-array-values-into-mongodb-where-element-is-not-in-array/51563408#51563408

Comment: it works fine, just have to add _id: 'xxxxx' of specific doc

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it since mongoDB version 4.4 is using [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) with a [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) step:

1. `$addFields` with `data` to add and create a new `keys` field that contains the existing keys.
2. `$filter` the `data` to include only items with keys that are not in the original array called 'additional'.
3. `$concatArrays`: 'additional' and the filtered `data` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate({_id: 'xxxx'}, [
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: [{key: "city", label: "CITY"}, {key: "city2", label: "CITY"}],
      keys: "$additional.key"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$item.key", "$keys"]}}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      additional: {$concatArrays: ["$additional", "$data"]},
      data: "$$REMOVE", keys: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FyOO8U_tsKx)