# Mongoose bulkwrite update - how to push new obj into an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkupdate

I have a model that looks like:

```
fname: String,
lname: String,
rating: [{
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      enum: RATING,
      default: 5
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
}]
```

I need to perform updates on this Model by adding new object inside the `rating array`, with new ratings and dates. I would like to use the `bulkwrite` method on `Model.collection` to do this because I need to enable bulk updates so that I don't have to update them one by one.

I created an `array bulkUpdateOperations = []` and did the following in a loop:

```
bulkUpdateOperations.push({
      'updateOne': {
        'filter': {'_id': item.id},
        'update': {$push: {rating: {'rating': item.rating, 'date': Date.now}}}
      }
});
Person.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOperations, {orderd: true, w: 1}, callbackfunc);
```

But nothing gets updated. I get the following response:

```
...
...
...
insertedCount: 0,
matchedCount: 0,
modifiedCount: 0,
deletedCount: 0,
upsertedCount: 0,
upsertedIds: {},
insertedIds: {},
n: 0 }
```

I would be very thankful if someone helped me through this problem.

**EDIT**

Here is the array I'm sending as POST body to update the records:

```
[{
    "id": "5b7d4d348151700014d25bdd",
    "rating": 1
},{
    "id": "5b771d10c1e03e1e78b854c2",
    "rating": 1
},{
    "id": "5b771d7ac1e03e1e78b854c8",
    "rating": 1
},{
    "id": "5b7bd75a33f88c1af8585be0",
    "rating": 1
},{
    "id": "5b814a2322236100142ac9f6",
    "rating": 1
}]
```

And here is a sample collection in the DB

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b7d4d348151700014d25bdd"
    },
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "fname": "mr. client",
    "lname": "good client",
    "contact_info": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b7d4d348151700014d25bde"
        },
        "mobile_no": "0011223344",
        "phone_no": "11223344"
    },
    "handlers": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b7d4d348151700014d25bdf"
            },
            "date": {
                "$date": "2018-08-22T11:47:00.544Z"
            },
            "id": {
                "$oid": "5b7d45fbfb6fc007d8bdc1f4"
            }
        }
    ],
    "onboarding_date": {
        "$date": "2018-08-22T11:47:00.551Z"
    },
    "rating": [
    {
        "rating": 5,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b814a8e22236100142ac9fc"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": "2018-08-25T12:22:59.584Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "rating": 3,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b814a8e22236100142ac9fb"
        },
        "date": {
            "$date": "2018-08-25T12:24:46.368Z"
        }
    }
],
    "__v": 0
}
```

**EDIT**
Adding `upsert: true` as a filter for `updateOne` creates a new document with only `rating` as its value.

**SOLUTION**

replace

```
'filter': {'_id': item.id},
```

by

```
'filter': {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.id)},
```

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801033/mongoose-add-multiple-object-to-array-if-not-exist-based-on-key/51808332#51808332

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet but that's pretty much what I'm doing

Comment: Might be your `item.id` is incorrect...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I checked again. I have 5 records to test this bulkwrite with and all ids do exist in the database

Comment: can you post collection and the array

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have updated the question with request body and a sample document from the database

Comment: You above code is working for me... The only thing I have changed replacing `Date.now` to `new Date()` and here is the output `BulkWriteResult {
  result:
   { ok: 1,
     writeErrors: [],
     writeConcernErrors: [],
     insertedIds: [],
     nInserted: 0,
     nUpserted: 0,
     nMatched: 1,
     nModified: 1,
     nRemoved: 0,
     upserted: [] },
  insertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {},
  insertedIds: {},
  n: 0 }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I resolved it!! replaced `'filter': {'_id': item.id}` with `'filter': {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.id)}` and its working!

Comment: not sure why but mongoose itself cast string to objectid... You can answer to your own post as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
bulkUpdateOperations.push({
      'updateOne': {
        'filter': {'_id': item.id},
        'update': {$push: {rating: {'rating': item.rating, 'date': Date.now}}}
      }
});
```

to

```
bulkUpdateOperations.push({
      'updateOne': {
        'filter': {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.id)},
        'update': {$push: {rating: {'rating': item.rating, 'date': Date.now}}}
      }
});
```

worked. Notice the type cast I had to manually perform in

```
'filter': {'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.id)},
```

I thought mongoose would automatically cast the `string` to an `ObjectId` type, but maybe because I'm dropping down a level of abstraction by using `Person.collection`, mongoose did not auto-cast the `itemId`.

Please feel free to update this answer if anyone can confirm why I had to cast the string manually.