# Bulk Update MongoDB documents using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

What would be the best way to update one field for all the documents in a mongodb database?

lets say this is my array of objects

```
const data = [
  {
    _id: '21381ubdjhbajhda',
    name: 'Samuel'
  },
  {
    _id: '21381ubdj2222bajhda',
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    _id: '21384441ubdjhbajhda',
    name: 'David'
  },
  and 45000 items more
]
```

so the easiest way would be

```
async function updateAll () {
  const data = [
    {
      _id: '21381ubdjhbajhda',
      name: 'Samuel'
    },
    {
      _id: '21381ubdj2222bajhda',
      name: 'Jack'
    },
    {
      _id: '21384441ubdjhbajhda',
      name: 'David'
    },
    and 45000 items more
  ]
  await Promise.all(data.map(async (element) => {
    const {_id, name} = element;
    findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { $set: { name: name } }, function(err,data) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
    });
  }));
}
```

And another method would be using the bulk operation which would be like below **but it doesnt work**:

```
function updateAll () {

  var bulk = db.persons.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  data.map((element) => {
    const {_id, name} = element;
    bulk.find( { _id: _id } ).update( { $set: { name: name } } );
  })

  bulk.execute();
}
```

But is there any other better ways to do this? Any suggestions on how to update documents in bulk? please keep in mind that the field Im trying to update varies from document to document. 
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose add multiple object to array if not exist based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801033/mongoose-add-multiple-object-to-array-if-not-exist-based-on-key)