# MongoDB multiple updates, multiple criterias, one operation

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to fire multiple updates with different criteria, in only one Mongo update command?

Let's say I have the following collection:

```
db.createCollection("receipts");
db.receipts.insert({"items": [{name: "Item 1", code: 123}, {name: "Item 2", code: 456}]});
db.receipts.insert({"items": [{name: "Item 3", code: 998}, {name: "Item 4", code: 557}, {name: "Item 1", code: 123}]});
```

Now, for example, I want the following updates (natural language):

- For every item with `code` 123, change it to 663;
- For every item with `code` 998, change it to 887;
- ...

My expectation is:

```
db.receipts.updateMany(...)
```

...or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [**bulk update**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801033/mongoose-add-multiple-object-to-array-if-not-exist-based/51808332#51808332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Bulk.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) ?

Comment: Yes I think so! Thanks!